# how to install entity framework core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to install the following nuget package:

`install-package microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver`

However I'm getting this exception:

```
Restoring packages for C:\Users\alex.ggg\source\repos\ccp\ccp.Rag\ccp.Rag.csproj...
install-package : NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.0 is not 
compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.0 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver -ProjectName  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.Powe 
   rShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 
install-package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ccp.Rag'.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver -ProjectName  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.Powe 
   rShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.4679650
```

**How do we install entityframeworkcore?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are targeting `netcoreapp3.1`, so try installing latest 3.1 [version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/3.1.21) of the package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 3.1.21
```